# Which topological spaces can be realized as simplicial complexes?

Tags: general-topology, simplicial-complex

My question is as the title suggests:

Which topological spaces can be realized as simplicial complexes (possibly abstract simplicial complex)?

A secondary question is which spaces can be realized as **finite** simplicial complexes?

I am aware of certain values which are defined for simplicial complexes, and wonder whether one can define them on topological space if they can be realized as a simplicial complex. My primary motivating example is the Euler characteristic, which is also defined on manifolds. To this end I was wondering which topological spaces could we try to extrapolate the definition of Euler characteristic?

I suspect that simplicial complexes can only be used to realize locally euclidean spaces, but perhaps some here happens to know the answer?

Comment: Your question seems to originate in the context of the Euler characteristic. This can be defined for general topological spaces. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic.